# Cant start up SQL service after server restart

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, local-security-policy

After Server restart Cant start SQL Service. Getting error :

```
Service: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS 
Domain and account: NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

This service account does not have the required user right "Log on as a service."

User Action

Assign "Log on as a service" to the service account on this computer. You can use Local Security Settings (Secpol.msc) to do this. If this computer is a node in a cluster, check that this user right is assigned to the Cluster service account on all nodes in the cluster.
```

In "log on as a service" window The buttton add User or Group is disabled.

So cant add any user/group ..

server: WindowsServer 2008 R2

Im connected throw remote desktop.

,Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the service account to "Network Service"

Start - Admin Tools - Services or Start - Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Services

Find "Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS)" - Right Click - Properties

Select the Log On tab - click Browse - type "Network Service" - click "OK" - click "OK"

Right click "Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS)" - Start

Comment: Thanks it fixed it. But what it changed ?
How can i mark your answer - helpful ?

Comment: I don't know why or how it changed.  To mark answers "helpful" click the up arrow next to the answer. You can also accept one answer by clicking the "check mark" under the vote count.